# Error after redirection using CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

I have created some code called `LoginController`. Whenever `Admin` gets successfully logged in I redirect the page to `index`.

However, I got an error like "problem on loading page".

This is my code:

```
<?php
class LoginController extends AdminAppController {
var $name = 'Login';
var $uses = array('Admin.Login');
var $sessionkey= '';
/*function beforeFilter()
{

    if($this->Session->read('user')=='Admin' || $this->params['action']=='login')
    {
        echo "in"; exit;
    }
    else
    {
        echo "else"; exit;
        $this->Session->setFlash('Login first','flash_failure');
        $this->redirect(array('action'=>'login'));

    }
}*/

function index() {


}

function login()
{
    //pr($this->data); exit;

    if(!empty($this->data))
    {
        $results = $this->Login->findByEmail($this->data['Login']['email']);
        if(!empty($results) && $results['Login']['password']== md5($this->data['Login']['password']))
        {   

            $this->Session->write('user', 'Admin');

            $results['Login']['last_login']=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
            $this->Login->save($results);
            $this->Session->setFlash('Login successfully.', 'flash_success');
            $this->redirect(array('controller'=>'login','action' => 'index'));



        }

    }
}
}
?>
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't it better to save roles in your DB so you can have multiple admins?

Comment: Also, maybe it's a good idea to post the complete error. I know you're new here, but always provide as much information as possible.

Comment: I would be using the Auth component rather than trying to build a whole login system.

Answer (score 0):

I got your problem.

IT goes into the infinite loop.ANd that is why you got  in the Page loading error.

As you did not distinguish between admin login and client login you are facing this issue.

So my suggestion is that create new same function with diff name called as admin login

And set the router for admin login.
regards,
ARCHIT.